# Why list is replacing the old object with new object

Tags: java, arraylist, jaxb

I am trying to read the object through xml using JAXB and updating some info the saving back.
here is the read and update code-

```
dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
document = dbuilder.parse(file);
jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(OutletWisePlanningListContainer.class);
Binder<Node> binder = jc.createBinder();
owpLContainer = (OutletWisePlanningListContainer)     
binder.unmarshal(document);
owpLContList = owpLContainer.getOwpList();
```

then - updating the objects

```
for (OutletWisePlanningList owpl1 : owpLContList) {
    owpl = owpl1.getOwpList();
    owpList = new OutletWisePlanningList();
    owpList = owpl1;
    skuList.add(owpl1.getSkuId());
    for (i = 1; i < sku; i++) {
        if (owpl1.getSkuId().trim().equals(request.getParameter("skuId" + i).trim())) {
            owpl1.getSkuId();
            ArrayList idList = new ArrayList();
            int j = 1, cnt = 1;
            al1.clear();
            int perf = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("hdnPerf" + i));
            for (OutletWisePlanning owps : owpl) {
                owp = new OutletWisePlanning();
                for (j = 1; j < perf; j++) { //used only when Planned outlets is changed
                    if (owp.getMarketIntId().trim().equals(request.getParameter("UID" + i + '-' + j).trim()) && !request.getParameter("txtTARGET_SETvolume" + i + '-' +  j).trim().equals("0")) {
                        //some updation in owp object
                        al1.add(owp);    
                    }
                }
                if (request.getParameter("selPlanUnplanned").equals("0")) { //used when Unplanned in    selected
                    al1.add(owp);
                }
            }
            owpList.setOwpList(al1);
            owpList.setSkuId(owpl1.getSkuId());
        }
    }
    owpList1.add(owpList);
    Iterator itr = owpList1.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        OutletWisePlanningList op1 = (OutletWisePlanningList) itr.next();
        for (OutletWisePlanning op2 : op1.getOwpList()) {
            System.out.println("Party id in the owpList1" + op2.getPartyId());
        }
    }   
}
al.addAll(owpList1);
```

And the xml from where i am reading data and updating the same-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OutletWisePlanningListContainer>
<OutletWisePlanningList skuId="4214">
    <OutletWisePlanning partyId="14560">
        <marketIntId>14002</marketIntId>
        <perfAllocId>818</perfAllocId>
        <relPartyName>Aangan (Indian North)</relPartyName>
        <addrLine1>Bhikaji Cama Place</addrLine1>
        <locationName>-NA-</locationName>
        <planQty>30</planQty>
        <planCpc>10</planCpc>
        <agreedQty>0</agreedQty>
        <agreedCpc>0</agreedCpc>
        <executedQty>0</executedQty>
        <executedCpc>0</executedCpc>
        <actualQty>0</actualQty>
        <actualCpc>0</actualCpc>
        <claimedQty>0</claimedQty>
        <claimedCpc>0</claimedCpc>
        <genCpc>0</genCpc>
        <eligibility></eligibility>
        <eligibleItem>0</eligibleItem>
    </OutletWisePlanning>
</OutletWisePlanningList>
<OutletWisePlanningList skuId="4215">
    <OutletWisePlanning partyId="14554">
        <marketIntId>14105</marketIntId>
        <perfAllocId>819</perfAllocId>
        <relPartyName>Dhaba (Indian North)</relPartyName>
        <addrLine1>Aurangzeb Road</addrLine1>
        <locationName>Aurangzeb Road</locationName>
        <planQty>44</planQty>
        <planCpc>10</planCpc>
        <agreedQty>0</agreedQty>
        <agreedCpc>0</agreedCpc>
        <executedQty>0</executedQty>
        <executedCpc>0</executedCpc>
        <actualQty>0</actualQty>
        <actualCpc>0</actualCpc>
        <claimedQty>0</claimedQty>
        <claimedCpc>0</claimedCpc>
        <genCpc>0</genCpc>
        <eligibility></eligibility>
        <eligibleItem>0</eligibleItem>
    </OutletWisePlanning>
</OutletWisePlanningList>
```

I am getting the xml with different skuId(i.e. ok) but partyId = 14560 is replacing by partyId = 14554 with its whole data.
Please help

Comment: so my mind reading skills are failing me today ...

Answer (score 0):

This code has lot of unnecessary initializations and assignments. You should have to clear all those.
However to answer your question, my best guess is that the issue is with this for loop.

```
for (OutletWisePlanning owps : owpl) {
            owp = new OutletWisePlanning();
            for (j = 1; j < perf; j++) { //used only when Planned outlets is changed
                if (owp.getMarketIntId().trim().equals(request.getParameter("UID" + i + '-' + j).trim()) && !request.getParameter("txtTARGET_SETvolume" + i + '-' +  j).trim().equals("0")) {
                    //some updation in owp object
                    al1.add(owp);    
                }
            }
            if (request.getParameter("selPlanUnplanned").equals("0")) { //used when Unplanned in    selected
                al1.add(owp);
            }
    }
```

First you are initializing the owp inside the for-each loop. `owp = new OutletWisePlanning();` This is never been assigned any values still you are using it on the if condition. Here either the code is incomplete or you might have some initializations inside the constructor. Anyway within the inner for loop the "SAME OBJECT REFERENCE" gets modified and added to the list `al1` when the if conditions(both inside and outside the loop) satisfies. So no matter how many times you add the object to this list all will have the same value.